# Detect if the number in the array has been already input (C program)

Tags: c, arrays, repeat

I am kind of confused. I'd like to make a program where if the number in the array has been already input, then it will detect it and say it was repeated, so the program would tell the user to put another non-repeated integer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 5

int main()
{
    int array[SIZE];
    int i;
    int j;


    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        printf("[%d] Insert a number: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &array[i]);

        j = i - 1; // This is the closest that I've gotten guys. But I need to create a loop to make j be -1 until it finds a repeated number in the array.

        if (array[i] == array[j])
        {
            printf("The number is repeated");
            i--;
        }

        if (array[i] > 1000)
        {
            printf("Sorry, the number you entered cannot be bigger than 1000\n");
            i--;
        }

        if (array[i] < 0)
        {
            printf("Sorry, the number you entered cannot be less than 0\n");
            i--;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        printf("The array inside is %d\n", array[i]);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, I did something similar. I just put j = i - 1 so basically it will tell the program that it was repeated. However, I suppose that I should create a loop that will subtract -1 to j until it finds the repeated value (if there is one). I just not have any idea how to create that loop and make it work.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Well, the comment says it already: You must create a loop from 0 to j (exclusively). Where is the problem? Besides, you have a problem when `i == 0`, when `j == -1`, which is not a valid index. You also have a problem when a number isn't valid: You leave these slots as they are, whcih is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 5

int main() {

    int array[SIZE];
    int numberCount, repeatCount;


    for(numberCount = 0; numberCount < SIZE; numberCount++) {

        printf("[%d] Insert a number:\n>", numberCount + 1);
        scanf("%d", &array[numberCount]);

        for(repeatCount = 0; repeatCount < numberCount; repeatCount++) {
            if (array[numberCount] == array[repeatCount]) {
                printf("\nThe numbe is repeated\n");
                numberCount--;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (array[numberCount] < 0) {
            printf("\nSorry, the number you entered cannot be less than 0\n");
            numberCount--;
        }

        if (array[numberCount] > 1000) {
            printf("\nSorry, the number you entered cannot be bigger than 1000\n");
            numberCount--;
        }

    }

    printf("\n\n");

    for(numberCount = 0; numberCount < SIZE; numberCount++)
        printf("The array inside is %d\n", array[numberCount]);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The checks can be done the following way (without testing)

```
int array[SIZE];
int i;


for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
{
    int valid = 1;
    int num;

    do
    {

        printf("[%d] Insert a number: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &num );

        if ( !( valid = !( num > 1000 ) ) )
        {
            printf("Sorry, the number you entered cannot be bigger than 1000\n");
        }
        else if ( !( valid = !( num < 0 ) ) )
        {
            printf("Sorry, the number you entered cannot be less than 0\n");
        }
        else
        {
            int j = 0;
            while ( j < i && num != array[j] ) j++;

            if ( !( valid = j == i ) )
            {
                printf("The number is repeated");
            }
        }
    } while ( !valid );

    array[i] = num;
}
```